# Prevent text breaking in paragraph

Tags: html, css

[Text breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrvWB.png)

How can I prevent text breaking in paragraph? I am using React js so i save my text in variable first then render it in jsx. My code be like:

```
  <h1>{singleArticle.title}</h1>
```

but it displays a text breaking

```
<p>"Eid al-Fitr Celebrated Through Distinct F
```

`amily Recipes"</p>`

What I want is:

```
<p>"Eid al-Fitr Celebrated Through Distinct
```

`Family Recipes"</p>`

Thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can't be sure from what you posted... But it feel like your `p` have `word-break: break-all;` somewhere in your CSS rules... Change it to `word-break: break-word;` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, text should be breaking as you would like it to, so you probably have this style floating around:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Try adding this style to your h1 tag:

```
word-break: normal !important;
```

In case you don't know, the "!important" means that this value should override any inherited styles.

Soucre: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found the problem. It's because I use `<Fade><p>{singleArticle.title}</p></Fade>` in my code. So, it render different element for every letter. Just like: `<span>E</span>` , `<span>I</span>` ... and so on. Then I remove the Fade component, it works perfectly